# Laravel Exception 405 MethodNotAllowed

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-exceptions

I'm trying to create a new "Airborne" test in my program and getting a 405 MethodNotAllowed Exception.

**Routes**

```php
Route::post('/testing/{id}/airbornes/create', [
    'uses' => 'AirborneController@create'
]);
```

**Controller**

```
public function create(Request $request, $id)
{
    $airborne = new Airborne;

    $newairborne = $airborne->newAirborne($request, $id);

    return redirect('/testing/' . $id . '/airbornes/' . $newairborne)->with(['id' => $id, 'airborneid' => $newairborne]);
}
```

**View**

```
<form class="sisform" role="form" method="POST" href="{{ URL::to('AirborneController@create', $id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {!! Form::token(); !!}
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        <i class="fas fa-plus fa-sm"></i> Create
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Which route throws the 405? The post or the redirect?

Comment: remove `{!! Form::token(); !!}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my knowledge forms don't have a href attribute. I think you suppose to write **Action** but wrote **href**.
Please specify **action** attribute in the form that you are trying to submit.

```
<form method="<POST or GET>" action="<to which URL you want to submit the form>">
```

in your case its

```
<form method="POST" ></form>
```

And action attribute is missing. If action attribute is missing or set to ""(Empty String), the form submits to itself (the same URL).

For example, you have defined the route to display the form as

```
Route::get('/airbornes/show', [
    'uses' => 'AirborneController@show'
    'as' => 'airborne.show'
]);
```

and then you submit a form without action attribute. It will submit the form to same route on which it currently is and it will look for post method with the same route but you dont have a same route with a POST method. so you are getting MethodNotAllowed Exception.

Either define the same route with post method or explicitly specify your action attribute of HTML form tag.

Let's say you have a route defined as following to submit the form to

```
Route::post('/airbornes/create', [
        'uses' => 'AirborneController@create'
        'as' => 'airborne.create'
    ]);
```

So your form tag should be like

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('airborne.create') }}">
//your HTML here
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` signposts that your route isn't available for the HTTP request method specified. Perhaps either because it isn’t defined correctly, or it has a conflict with another similarly named route.

**Named Routes**

Consider using named routes to allow for the convenient generation of URLs or redirects. They can generally be much easier to maintain.

```php
Route::post('/airborne/create/testing/{id}', [
    'as' => 'airborne.create',
    'uses' => 'AirborneController@create'
]);
```

**Laravel Collective**

Use Laravel Collective's Form:open tag and remove Form::token()

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['airborne.create', $id], 'method' =>'post']) !!}

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="fas fa-plus fa-sm"></i> Create
</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**dd() Helper Function**

The dd function dumps the given variables and ends execution of the script. Double-check your Airborne class is returning the object or id you expect.

```
dd($newairborne)
```

**List available routes**

Always make sure your defined routes, views, and actions match up.

```
php artisan route:list --sort name
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of All**
Form don't have href attribute, it has "`action`"

```
<form class="sisform" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('AirborneController@create', $id) }}">
```

---

**Secondly**
If the above change doesn't work, you can make some changes like:

**1. Route**
Give your route a name as:

```
Route::post('/testing/{id}/airbornes/create', [
    'uses' => 'AirborneController@create',
    'as'   => 'airborne.create',         // <---------------
]);
```

**2. View**
Give route name with `route()` method in form action rather than `URL::to()` method:

```
<form class="sisform" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('airborne.create', $id) }}">
```